# Which preposition is to be used before "participation" -- in or on?

Tags: prepositions

I read a sentence in Word by Word by Kory Stamper which was:

> I had one social studies teacher who proclaimed to us on the first day of class that everyone was expected to speak "correct and proper English" in class and  failure to do so would mean marks off on participation.

I don't know what sort of "participation" is he talking about here? Is it class participation of a student? And what should be the preposition before it? In or on?

Comment: Duplicate; already asked (6 hrs ago) on ELL by "kelvin".

Comment: The duplicate is ["
Which preposition to use before participation — in or on?"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/220101/which-preposition-to-use-before-participation-in-or-on), and the most common preposition is neither of those, but **for**.

Answer (score -2):

You are correct. The teacher is talking about class participation. And the preposition is already correct.

You mark students **on** their class participation, not **in** their class participation.